# Error on Pycharm: ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, importerror

I'm, working on Windows 8 and I receive this error when launching my python program on pycharm:

```
ImportError: No module named Qwt5

    refered to the line: "import PyQt4.Qwt5 as Qwt"
```

the program always worked till today, and the IDE still suggests me Qwt5 as a module to import when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, so it seems is still recognized.

I checked the Qwt5 folder and there is the `__init__.py` file

I use Python 2.7.9 an is correctly selected as Python Interpreter

I've already tried to remove the packages and reinstall them.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and working.`sudo apt-get install python-qwt5-qt4`